# C++ Detect input redirection

Tags: c++, iostream, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe in C/C++/Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt)

Consider we got a small program which takes some standard C input.

I would like to know if the user is using input redirection, for example like this:

```
./programm < in.txt
```

Is there a way to **detect** this way of input redirecting **in** the program?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216529/check-for-unix-command-line-arguments-pipes-and-redirects-from-a-c-program

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027484/determine-whether-process-output-is-being-redirected-in-c-c

Comment: Why do you need to know. The whole point is to make the input look the same.

Comment: @LokiAstari: You might want to prompt the user for input when reading from a terminal, and not otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no portable way to do that, since C++ says nothing about where `cin` comes from. On a Posix system, you can test whether or not `cin` comes from a terminal or is redirected using [`isatty`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isatty.3.html), something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    // not redirected
} else {
    // redirected
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On a posix system you can use the [isatty function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty). The standard input is [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles) 0.

```
isatty(0); // if this is true then you haven't redirected the input
```

Comment: Instead of `0` you could say `fileno(std::stdin)`, though :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Or `STDIN_FILENO`, if you don't want an unnecessary function call.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C++, you can't. However on Posix systems you can using isatty:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int const fd_stdin = 0;
int const fd_stdout = 1;
int const fd_stderr = 2;

int main()
{
  if (isatty(fd_stdin)) 
    std::cout << "Standard input was not redirected\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Standard input was redirected\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX system you can test if stdin, i.e. fd 0 is a TTY:

```
#include <unistd.h>

is_redirected() {
    return !isatty(0) || !isatty(1) || !isatty(2);
}

is_input_redirected() {
    return !isatty(0);
}

is_output_redirected() {
    return !isatty(1) || !isatty(2);
}

is_stdout_redirected() {
    return !isatty(1);
}

is_stderr_redirected() {
    return !isatty(2);
}
```

This is not part of the C++ standard library, but if running on a POSIX system part of the evailable ecosystem your program is going to live in. Feel free to use it.