# There's something from stdin or not?

Tags: c, file, stdin, argv, argc

It's possible to make a code that recognizes whether a file was passed like:

```
program.out < file.dat
```

I search an answer for this because I want to write code to do something like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char filename[50];

    if ( argc > 1 )
    {
        strcpy (filename, argv[1]);
    }

    else if ( SOMETHING )
    {
        /* copy the stdin into fin (?) */
    }

    FILE *fin;

    fin = fopen (filename, "r");

    /* ... */

    fclose(fin);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

In which `SOMETHING` evaluates to 1 if the file was passed with `<`, and 0 otherwise.

If it's possible, I am looking for a solution working in standard C.

Comment: The usual convention is that the user passes the filename as an argument, and if they don't provide a filename argument you read from stdin. Why are you violating this?

Comment: _@Barmar_. I'm not violating this, I'm asking what I should do to do what you have say! How can I read from stdin only if _"they don't provide a filename argument"_?

Comment: No, you're doing the opposite. You're reading from a hard-coded filename if they don't redirect the input.

Comment: Now I have edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot detect this in ISO C (that is, without resorting to platform extensions, like getting the file descriptor using `fileno` on POSIX and then running some tests on it by obtaining attributes with `fstat` and so forth.)

The `stdin` stream is required by ISO C to be line buffered if it is connected to an interactive device.  This doesn't help us, however, since there are no portable functions to inquire about the buffering mode of a `FILE *`: there are only "setters", no "getters". The GNU C library has a `__flbf (FILE *stream)` which reports whether or not a stream is line-buffered, but it is an obvious extension, declared in a `<stdio_ext.h>` header.

If your program must work with a file, and not with standard input from an interactive device, then a good solution is to make the argument to the program mandatory. Make it require a filename argument and always open that file. Then you're sure you have the file.

You can also make the argument optional, and if it is missing, then open a default file, ignoring `stdin`.

You can also use `freopen` to make `stdin` point to a file. Then code which works with `stdin` implicitly will take input from that file:

Pseudo-code:

```
name = "some default"

if we have an argument
  name = that argument

if (freopen(name, mode, stdin) == 0)
   handle error
else
   stdin is now a file; process it
```

If you really must support the `program < file` situation, while flagging the `program` situation (interactive input) as invalid, you need the aforementioned platform-specific hacks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with a Unix-specific solution, you can use `isatty()`:

```
FILE *fin;
int need_to_close;

if (isatty(fileno(STDIN))) { // I/O not redirected
    fin = fopen("file.dat", "r");
    need_to_close = 1;
} else {
    fin = stdin;
    need_to_close = 0;
}

/* ... */

if (need_to_close) {
    fclose(fin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079239/2003263) can help:
It says,

> On a Posix system, you can test whether or not cin comes from a
>   terminal or is redirected using [isatty](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isatty.3.html)

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    // not redirected
} else {
    // redirected
}
```